# iPhone: UIView with 1 pixel height

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to create a `UIView` with 1 pixel height.

```
     UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,20,1)];
```

On a non-Retina iPhone it's ok, but on Retina it looks like 2 pixels height.

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On retina actual pixels and UIKit pixels are different.

Try this:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,20,1/[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale])];
```

Comment: This is not a good idea, the framework handles the scaling. That's why on retina you still got 320 x 480 px.

Comment: this is the correct way to do it - your solution will be one real pixel on retina and half a pixel on non-retina. My solution is one real pixel in both cases.

Comment: But my solution keeps all over proportions correct. Your solution will cause that the line will take twice as much space on non-retina. I think it's not a good idea at all to take advantage of 0.5 pixels if you want to support non-retina. And nobody wants to use 1/[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]) over and over again

Comment: @BenClayton non-retina doesn't draw half pixels, it just seems to round them up to full pixels, so both of the solutions actually yield the same result.

Answer (score 1):

That's because CGRectMake uses **points** not **pixels**. 
On retina devices they doubled dpi, so for 1 point you now have 2 pixels. 
On non-retina devices **1 point = 1 pixel**.